# Type error in C++ when instantiating a priority_queue of int pairs with a custom comparator (to implement a min heap)

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue

Currently working through a leetcode problem for which I need a min Heap of pairs.
I am trying to use a `priority_queue` with `int` `pair`s and a custom compare type.
Attempts of implementation of the same have failed with the following error:

> In file included from prog_joined.cpp:1:
> In file included from ./precompiled/headers.h:55:
> In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/queue:64:
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_queue.h:467:7: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_same<int, std::pair<int, int>>::value' "value_type must be the same as the underlying container"
> static_assert(is_same<_Tp, typename _Sequence::value_type>::value,
> ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Line 9: Char 67: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int>>>, std::greater>' requested here
> priority_queue<int, vector<pair<int, int>>, greater> pq;

Here's the code with which I'm trying to implement the heap:

```
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
//...
priority_queue<int, pair<int, int>, greater<int>> pq;
```

Comment: That code does not agree with the error message. Is your copy-and-paste broken?

Comment: There's more to the code but this is where the error message is pointing to.

Comment: A priority queue of *pairs* of `int` would begin `std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, ...` and requires a comparator for such pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [`std::priority_queue` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

- The **1st** template argument is the **data** type (should be `pair<int,int>` in your case).
- The **2nd** template argument should be the **underlying container** type used for the queue.
- The **3rd** should be the **compare** type.

**For example** if you want a `priority_queue` of `int` `pair`s that use `std::vector` as a container, **you need:**

```cpp
std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>,                  // data type
                    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>,      // container type
                    std::greater<std::pair<int,int>>> pq; // compare type
```

**Note:** as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) the `std::pair` implementation for comparison operators which are used by `std::greater` is:

> Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically by operator<, that is, compares
> the first elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the
> second elements.

If this is not what you need you can implement your own compare type for `std::pair<int,int>`.

**A side note:** it is better to avoid `using namespace std`. See here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: While searching the internet I came across an instance where a heap was implemented with priority_queue<pair<int, int>> and it seemed to work, according to the post. Any reason why that worked?
Link to the post:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-queue-of-pairs-in-c-ordered-by-first/

Comment: The default container is `std::vector` anyway. But the default compare type is `std::less`, so it should not behave as `std::greater` (if indeed what you need is `std::greater`).

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate the help, I have another question:
Tried implementing a min heap as shown below, but am still getting a compilation error. Is there something fundamental that I'm missing when trying to create a heap?
priority_queue<pair<double, vector<int>>, pair<double, vector<int>>, greater<pair<double, vector<int>>>> pq;

Comment: The 2nd is the container type, so you need (with `vector` as container): `priority_queue<pair<double, vector<int>>, vector<pair<double, vector<int>>>, greater<pair<double, vector<int>>>> pq;`

Comment: @HemantSharma You should **not** modify your question after you've got a valid answer, so I will roll it back. If my last comment above did not help please post a new question.

Comment: thanks for the help. I did not know I couldn't do that, will be careful about it in the future.

And with this my doubts are all cleared. Thanks for that too.

Comment: And I'll also not be using namespace std in the future, thanks for the extra help.

Answer (score 0):

for this , If you are trying to implement a minheap and that to in pair using this might solve your problem as solving a leetcode problem i also faced similar issues

priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>, greater<pair<int,int>>>pq;